# Jaxb gives me java.lang,IllegalArgumentException the uri may not be the empty string in Tomcat and WebLogic server

Tags: java, jaxb, apache-axis

I have created xsd using jaxb,with help of xsd created wsdl.Its working fine in Jboss server.
But not working in Both WebLogic and Tomcat server.While sending request in soapui it will give the response like this

"java.lang.IllegalArgumentException the uri may not be the empty string"

Comment: We need at least more of the stack trace, and some hint of the code in question.

Comment: Have you configured the endpoint of the service in the sbconsole to point to SoapUI?